# Let a function accept different types for the same variable?

Tags: c++

I have to make a function accept either *string* or *int* for the first and second variable its declaring:

```
char safe_at(int position, string s){ // example when the first is int and the second is string
    if (position < s.length()){

        return s[position];
    }
    else {
        return ' ';
    }
}

char safe_at(string s, int position){ // example when the first is string and the second is int
    if (position < s.length()){

        return s[position];
    }
    else {
        return ' ';
    }
}
```

I'm not sure you can do it the way I am describing. 
My assignment requires me to only use one function, which confuses me.

Comment: "string or int for the first and second variable" ? Please clarify. `int` has no `length` member function, hence passing an `int` as second parameter wont work

Comment: I mean that 'position' can be either string or int, and the same for 's'. I'm used to python so sorry if I'm not using the right terminology.

Comment: Even in python that makes no sense! If your function is written in a way where the code is useful for different types, it is ok, but what s[position] be if position itself is a string???

Comment: The question doesn't make any sense. One can make function that accepts either string or int via, say, variant or by making two functions. Or one can make function that accepts both variables. It can operate similarly to a function that accepts a single variable by making some logic which variable to process. One cannot make function that accepts two variables that actually accepts only one variable. You'd better figure out what is the actual question.

Comment: Please explain what you want the function to do for the combinations of parameters you want to pass. It is not obvious.

Comment: Taking your edit into account, I'm assuming you are looking for [function overloading](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-overloading-c/)

Comment: I updated the code. Basically, both functions accept a string and int, but in opposite order. It must be one function, however, that can accept in either order.

Comment: @picklemaster Uh, but it's already like that, no? If the two functions have the same name, it should already work.

Comment: @picklemaster why do you need this? It makes no sense to create two separate functions that have the exact same parameters just in a different order. Unless you are trying to write a bridge between two APIs with similar functions, for instance.

Answer (score 3):

If you are coming from Python, you have a lot to learn about type-safety (or unlearn about dynamic typing, depending on how you see it ;). A function can only take parameters of fixed type. However, you can overload functions:

Lets assume you have this:

> ```
> char safe_at(int position, string s){ // example when the first is int and the second is string
>     if (position < s.length()){
>
>         return s[position];
>     }
>     else {
>         return ' ';
>     }
> }
> ```

And now you want to enable calling the function with the order of the parameters swapped, then you can provide an overload like this:

```
char safe_at(int position, string s) {
    return safe_at(s,position);
}
```

In a nutshell, the function to call is determined by the types of the supplied parameters and we can reuse the implementation. Then

```
 std::string f{"foo"};
 int x = 42;
 auto c = safe_at(f,x);
 c = safe_at(x,f);
```

..the first call will resolve to a call to `safe_at(std::string,int)` and the second will call `safe_at(int,std::string)`.

**PS** Actually your code is fine as is, but of course you want to avoid code duplication.

**PPS**

> My assignment requires me to only use one function, which confuses me.

There must be a small misunderstanding somewhere, because it can be done with a single function, but that wouldn't be trivial and certainly overkill for this situation. Colloquially when talking about "functions" actually a full overload set is considered. Even `std::string::length` is actually two functions. It has a `const` and a non-const overload (see [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size)).

**PPPS** I suppose this is a task given to you. It is not clear why you are supposed to write the fucntion such that the order of parameters can be swapped. Functions that have more than one parameter can be a source of confusion and errors. Consider

```
void foo(int x,char z);
```

Then both following ways to call it will compile

```
int x = 42;
char y = 0;
foo(x,y);
foo(y,x);
```

Writing parameters in the wrong order can happen by mistake. Writing a fucntion that allows to swap paramters does not really help on that, it rather adds confusion. In my opinion the aim of your taks is rather questionable.

Comment: Thanks, this is indeed what I was looking for.

Comment: @picklemaster glad to help, consider to accept this answer, if you think it is an acceptable answer ;)